# not able to create materialized view of union based complex query

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I am trying to create materialized view (fast refresh method) but its throwing error

> ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a
> complex query error.

I can't change the query because it's been using in our Oracle Apex application but it's a view originally I have to convert it in MV. Please suggest which kind of materialized view will be suitable for my query which contains 32 tables along with unions and analytic functions.

```
create materialized view SAMPLE
    refresh fast
    as
    select ms.employee_id,
           ms.sal_code code,
           'SALARY' Account_type,
           UPPER(sb.salary_breakup) Account_title,
           sb.account_code ACCOUNT_CODE,
           ('ADDITION') AMOUNT_TYPE,
           sb.pay_type PAY_TYPE,
           p.display_title PAY_TITLE,
           ms.salary AMOUNT,
           p.order_in_payroll,
           to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=p.org_id and account_id=1) || substr(sb.sal_code,3,3)) Code_order,
           ms.month,
           sb.tax_exemption,
           sb.taxtation_type,
           'Y' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME,
           p.org_id
           from PAY_MONTHLY_SALARY ms,pay_salary_breakups sb,PAYROL_TYPE p
           where ms.sal_code=sb.sal_code
          and p.pay_type=sb.pay_type
           --order by sb.sal_code
    union
    -----ALLOWANCE PART
    select mad.employee_id,
           mad.ad_code code,
           ad.type Account_type,
           UPPER(ad.ad_name) Account_title,
           ad.account_code ACCOUNT_CODE,
           'ADDITION' AMOUNT_TYPE,
          ad.pay_type PAY_TYPE,
          p.display_title PAY_TITLE,
           mad.amount AMOUNT,
           p.order_in_payroll,
           to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=p.org_id and account_id=2) || substr(mad.ad_code,3,3)) Code_order,
           mad.month,
           ad.tax_exemption,
           ad.taxtation_type,
           'Y' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME,
           p.org_id
           from Pay_Month_Allow_Ded mad,pay_allowance_deduction_setup ad,PAYROL_TYPE p
           where mad.ad_code=ad.ad_code
           and p.pay_type=ad.pay_type
           and ad.type ='ALLOWANCE'
           --order by ad.ad_code
    
    union
    -----DEDUCTION PART
    select mad.employee_id,
           mad.ad_code code,
           ad.type Account_type,
           UPPER(ad.ad_name) Account_title,
           ad.account_code ACCOUNT_CODE,
          'DEDUCTION' AMOUNT_TYPE,
          ad.pay_type PAY_TYPE,
          p.display_title PAY_TITLE,
           mad.amount AMOUNT,
           p.order_in_payroll,
           to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=p.org_id and account_id=3) || substr(mad.ad_code,3,3)) Code_order,
           mad.month,
           ad.tax_exemption,
           ad.taxtation_type,
           'Y' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME,
           p.org_id
           from Pay_Month_Allow_Ded mad,pay_allowance_deduction_setup ad,PAYROL_TYPE p
           where mad.ad_code=ad.ad_code
           and p.pay_type=ad.pay_type
           and ad.type='DEDUCTION'
           --order by ad.ad_code
    
    union
    ---- FUNDS AND CONTRIBUTION PART
    select e.employee_id
    ,fcs.fc_code
    ,'FUNDS' Account_type
    ,UPPER(fct.fc_type_name) ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,(case when fct.type='EMPLOYEE' then fcs.account_code_credit
           when fct.type='EMPLOYER' then fcs.account_code
             end) ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,(case when fct.type='EMPLOYEE' then 'DEDUCTION'
           when fct.type='EMPLOYER' then 'OTHERTAX'
             end) AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,r.amount AMOUNT
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=4) || substr(fcs.fc_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,r.month
    ,(case when fcs.TAX_EXEMPTION='Y' then fcs.tax_exemption
           when fcs.TAX_EXEMPTION='N' then fct.tax_exemption
             end) TAX_EXEMPTION,
            fcs.taxtation_type,
           'Y' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME,
           pt.org_id
    from
    hr_employee_info e
    ,fund_contribution_records r
    ,fund_contributions_type fct
    ,fund_contributions_setup fcs
    ,payrol_type pt
    where e.employee_id=r.employee_id
    and r.contribution_type_id=fct.contribution_type_id
    and r.fc_code=fcs.fc_code
    and fct.fc_code=fcs.fc_code
    and fct.payroll_type=pt.pay_type
    
    union
    ----- ATTENDACE DATA PART
    select
    pmt.employee_id
    ,att.att_code
    ,'ATTENDANCE' Account_type
    ,UPPER(att.attendace_type) ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,NULL ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'ZERO' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,pmt.attendance_days AMOUNT
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=5) || substr(att.att_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,pmt.month
    ,'Y' TAX_EXEMPTION
    ,'NONE' taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,       pt.org_id
    from att_attendance_seup att
    ,pay_monthly_attendance pmt
    ,payrol_type pt
    where att.att_code=pmt.att_code
    and pt.pay_type=att.pay_type
    and pt.org_id=att.org_id
    
    /*union
    
    ---- TARGET DATA PART
    
    select
    pmt.employee_id
    ,pts.ta_code CODE
    ,UPPER(pts.target_name) ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,'ZERO' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,pmt.value AMOUNT
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number(5 || substr(pts.ta_code,4,1)) Code_order
    ,pmt.month
    ,'Y' TAX_EXEMPTION,
           pt.org_id
    from
    pay_monthly_targets pmt
    ,pay_target_setup pts
    ,payrol_type pt
    where pts.ta_code=pmt.ta_code
    and pt.pay_type=pts.pay_type*/
    
    union
    
    ----LOAN DISBURSEMENT PART
    
    
    select
    pmld.employee_id
    ,plns.ln_code code
    ,'LOAN DISBURSEMENT' Account_type
    ,UPPER(plns.loan_name) ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,plns.account_code ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'ADDITION' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,pmld.amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=6) || substr(plns.ln_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,pmld.month
    ,'Y' tax_exemption
    ,plns.taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,       pt.org_id
    from
    PAY_LOAN_SETUP plns
    ,pay_loan_monthly_disbursement pmld
    ,payrol_type pt
    where plns.ln_code=pmld.ln_code
    and plns.pay_type_disburse=pt.pay_type
    
    union
    
    ------- LOAN INSTALLMENTS PART
    select
    peld.employee_id
    ,plns.ln_code code
    ,'LOAN INSTALLMENT' Account_type
    ,UPPER(plns.loan_name || '(I)') ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,plns.account_code_installment ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'DEDUCTION' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,plei.amount amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=7) || substr(plns.ln_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,plei.month
    ,'Y' tax_exemption
    ,plns.taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,       pt.org_id
    from
    PAY_LOAN_SETUP plns
    ,PAY_EMP_LOAN_DISBURSEMENT peld
    ,PAY_EMP_LOAN_INSTALMENTS plei
    ,payrol_type pt
    where plns.ln_code=peld.ln_code
    and peld.loan_id=plei.loan_id
    and plns.pay_type=pt.pay_type
    and pt.org_id=plns.org_id
    
    
    -----LOAN MARKUP
    union
    
    select
    peld.employee_id
    ,plns.ln_code code
    ,'LOAN MARKUP' Account_type
    ,UPPER(plns.loan_name || '(M)') ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,plns.account_code_markup ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'DEDUCTION' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,plei.benchmark_taken amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=8) || substr(plns.ln_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,plei.month
    ,'Y' tax_exemption
    ,plns.taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,       pt.org_id
    from
    PAY_LOAN_SETUP plns
    ,PAY_EMP_LOAN_DISBURSEMENT peld
    ,PAY_EMP_LOAN_INSTALMENTS plei
    ,payrol_type pt
    where plns.ln_code=peld.ln_code
    and peld.loan_id=plei.loan_id
    and plns.pay_type=pt.pay_type
    
    --------REIMBURSEMENT PART
    
    union
    
    select
    hrc.employee_id
    ,hrs.re_code CODE
    ,'REIMBURSEMENT' Account_type
    ,UPPER(hrs.reimbursement_name) ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,hrs.account_code ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'ADDITION' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,hrc.amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=9) || substr(hrs.re_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,hrc.month
    ,hrs.tax_exemption
    ,hrs.taxtation_type
    ,'Y' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,       pt.org_id
    from
    hr_reimbursement_setup hrs
    ,pay_monthly_reimbursement hrc
    ,payrol_type pt
    ,hr_employee_info e
    where hrs.re_code=hrc.re_code
    and hrc.employee_id=e.employee_id
    and hrs.pay_type=pt.pay_type
    
    --------OTHER INCOME TAX PART
    
    
    union
    
    select d.employee_id
    ,to_char('OT'||lpad(d.itax_other_id,3,000)) CODE
    ,'OTHER TAXABLE' Account_type
    ,UPPER(s.name || '(OT)') ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,NULL ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'OTHERTAX' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,(case when s.type='ADDITION' then i.amount
           when s.type='EXEMPTION' then i.amount*-1
             end) Amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=10) || lpad(d.itax_other_id,3,000)) CODE_ORDER
    ,i.month
    ,'N' TAX_EXEMPTION
    ,s.taxtation_type
    ,s.include_in_mothly_income  INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,i.org_id
    from
    PAY_MONTHLY_OTHER_TAX_INCOME i
    ,ITAX_DECLARE_OTHER_EMP_INCOME d
    ,ITAX_OTHER_INCOME_SETUP s
    ,payrol_type pt
    where i.org_id=s.org_id
    and d.org_id=s.org_id
    and i.itax_declare_id=d.itax_declare_id
    and s.itax_other_id=d.itax_other_id
    and s.pay_type=pt.pay_type
    and s.org_id=pt.org_id
    
    -----TAXABLE INCOME(just to show)
    
    union
    
    select
    i.employee_id
    ,t.tx_code CODE
    ,'TAXABLE INCOME' Account_type
    ,'TAXABLE INCOME' ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,NULL ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'ZERO' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    , sum(i.amount) amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=i.org_id and account_id=11) || substr(t.tx_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,i.month
    ,'Y' TAX_EXEMPTION
    ,'NONE' taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,i.org_id
    from
    TAX_CODE_REGIONS t
    ,PAY_EMP_MONTHLY_TAXABLE_INCOME i
    ,payrol_type pt
    where t.tx_code=i.tx_code
    and i.INCLUDE_IN_MOTHLY_INCOME='Y'
    --and t.pay_type=pt.pay_type
    and pt.pay_type=Default_Value.GET_SYSTEM_DEFAULT('TXPAYTYPE',i.org_id)
    group by i.employee_id,t.tx_code,pt.pay_type,pt.display_title,pt.order_in_payroll,i.month,i.org_id
    
    
    
    --------Income Tax Part
    
    union
    
    
    select
    i.employee_id
    ,t.tx_code CODE
    ,'INCOME TAX' Account_type
    ,'INCOME TAX' ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,DEFAULT_VALUE.GET_SYSTEM_DEFAULT('ITAC',i.org_id) ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'DEDUCTION' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,i.amount amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=12) || substr(t.tx_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,i.month
    ,'Y' TAX_EXEMPTION
    ,'NONE' taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,i.org_id
    from
    TAX_CODE_REGIONS t
    ,pay_monthly_itax i
    ,payrol_type pt
    where t.tx_code=i.tx_code
    --and t.pay_type=pt.pay_type
    and pt.pay_type=Default_Value.GET_SYSTEM_DEFAULT('TXPAYTYPE',i.org_id)
    
    
    
    -----GRATUITY PART(only for report purpose)
    
    union
    
    select
    p.employee_id
    ,to_char('GP'||lpad(p.gratuity_id,3,000)) CODE
    ,'GRATUITY' Account_type
    ,UPPER(gs.name) ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,gs.account_code ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'ZERO' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,gs.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,p.amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=13) || lpad(p.gratuity_id,3,000)) CODE_ORDER
    ,p.month
    ,'Y' TAX_EXEMPTION
    ,'NONE' taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,pt.org_id
    from
    HR_GRATUITY_MONTHLY_ACCRUALS p,
    HR_GRATUITY_SETUP gs,
    payrol_type pt
    where p.gratuity_id=gs.gratuity_id
    and p.org_id=gs.org_id
    and gs.pay_type=pt.pay_type
    and p.org_id=pt.org_id
    
    ---------LEAVE ENCASHMENT PART
    
    union
    
    select
    LED.Employee_Id
    ,'LE'||lpad(lt.leave_type_id,3,0) CODE
    ,'ALLOWANCE' ACCOUNT_TYPE
    ,UPPER(lt.leave_name) ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,null ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'ADDITION' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,LED.Amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=2)||lpad(lt.leave_type_id,3,0)) CODE_ORDER
    ,LED.Month
    ,'N' TAX_EXEMPTION
    ,'VARIABLE' TAXTATION_TYPE
    ,'Y' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,LED.Org_Id
    from
    HR_LEAVE_ENCASHMENT_DISBRSE LED
    ,Hr_Leave_Type lt
    ,(select max(pt.order_in_payroll) order_in_payroll,pt.org_id from Payrol_Type pt group by pt.org_id) pt_a
    ,Payrol_Type pt
    where LED.Leave_Type_Id=lt.leave_type_id
    and LED.Org_Id=lt.org_id
    and LED.Org_Id=pt_a.org_id
    and pt_a.org_id=pt.org_id
    and pt_a.order_in_payroll=pt.order_in_payroll
    
    ------Generate Fake Lines For every Employee against pay_type
    
    union
    
    select
    e.employee_id
    ,'FAKE' CODE
    ,pt.display_title Account_type
    ,'FAKE' ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,pt.account_code ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'ZERO' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,0 AMOUNT
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,99991 CODE_ORDER
    ,pi.month
    ,'Y' TAX_EXEMPTION
    ,'NONE' taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,pi.org_id
    from
    PAY_MONTHLY_PROCESS_INFO pi
    ,hr_employee_info e
    ,payrol_type pt
    where pi.org_id=e.org_id
    and pi.org_id=pt.org_id
    and pi.month>=e.join_date;
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302 you have a restriction so you cant do it, either you have to rewrite the query to qualify or use different approach.

Comment: "Materialized views are not eligible for fast refresh if the defining query contains an analytic function or the XMLTable function."

Comment: I can't rewrite this query. I heard there is some MV regarding union too. Do u have any idea?

Comment: yes because union avoids duplicates and sorts the data, can you use union all instead ?

Comment: I used QUERY REWRITE it has solved previous error now getting error on where clause where plsql function is use that it's not supporting plsql function. any workaround for that?

Comment: and I can't remove that function

Comment: you should post it as another question, this is different to what asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for different approach -

You have a [restriction](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm) so you cant do it, either you have to rewrite the query to qualify or use different approach.

- Avoid union if you can see if you can use union all use it
  instead.
- Try to create multiple MV  on each queries that you    posted, not
  all of your queries has analytical functions.
- The  ones which you have analytical functions, those create it
  as views
- If you want to union then you just do it with sql or create a view

  like

  select * from mv1 union
  select * from view_1 union
  slect * from mv2 union
  ....

May be your database server might be on huge load if you have huge data with 30+ fast refresh MV, so please consult your DBA before implementing it.